# How to get previous month and previous year in MonthYear format (December2020) using Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I want the previous month & previous year in the format: "**December2020**". 
But while executing the below Linux command I'm getting July2020.

```
echo `date -d "2021-01-08" '+%B' -d 'last month'``date -d '1 year ago' +%Y
```

The date hardcoded parameter is in format: YYYY-MM-DD (2021-01-08)

Comment: yes, as I've given the date input as "2021-01-08" BUT, I want the output to be "December2020".
Is there any command to retrieve output as  "December2020" if the date is of "2021-01-08".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`date` accepts only one `-d` option. In your command `date -d "2021-01-08" '+%B' -d 'last month'` the first `-d` is ignored. Only the `-d "last month"` applies. Because of that, and since we have August right now, the output is `July`.

You probably wanted to use

```
date -d '2021-01-08 - 1 month' +%B%Y
```

which prints `December2020`.

If you really wanted to concat the previous month *and* previous year together, you could use

```
echo "$(date -d'2021-01-08 - 1 month' +%B)$(date -d'2021-01-08 - 1 year' +%Y)"
```

but that would give rather strange results:

```
2021-01-08 → December2020 # 1 month before input date
2021-04-30 → March2020    # 13 months before input date
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

Currently I'm using `CURRENT_DATE` variable in .profile. export `CURRENT_DATE=date +%Y-%m-%d`

How to incorporate the `CURRENT_DATE` variable in `date -d '$CURRENT_DATE - 1 month' +%B%Y` to get previous month and previous year.

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes: `date -d "$CURRENT_DATE - 1 month" +%B%Y`. But if you update the variable daily with the current date, there is no point in using a variable at all since you could use just `date -d 'last month' +%B%Y`.